# array_udiff with objects, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I got two arrays with stdClass objects with 3 members. All members of array `$deselectedIds` are members in the array `$ids`, but with different keys. I want them removed from array `$ids`. Tried this, without success:

```
$result = array_udiff($ids, $deselectedIds, function($a, $b) {
            return ($a->contactId == $b->contactId) && ($a->addressId == $b->addressId) && ($a->customerId == $b->customerId) ? 0 : 1;
        });
var_dump(count($result)) returns the same as var_dump(count($ids))
```

sample data:

```
$deselectedIds = array(
        "97830-90473-90253" => (object)array(
            "contactId" => "97830",
            "addressId" => "90473",
            "customerId" => "90253",
        ),
        "165837-146683-144677" => (object)array(
            "contactId" => "165837",
            "addressId" => "146683",
            "customerId" => "144677",
        ),
        "133004-119729-118853" => (object)array(
            "contactId" => "133004",
            "addressId" => "119729",
            "customerId" => "118853",
        ),
        "174081-153779-151573" => (object)array(
            "contactId" => "174081",
            "addressId" => "153779",
            "customerId" => "151573",
        )
    );


$ids = array(
        (object)array(
            "contactId" => 97830,
            "addressId" => 90473,
            "customerId" => 90253,
        ),
        (object)array(
            "contactId" => 213424,
            "addressId" => 23423,
            "customerId" => 234234,
        ),
        (object)array(
            "contactId" => 57675,
            "addressId" => 756765,
            "customerId" => 57567,
        ),
        (object)array(
            "contactId" => 165837,
            "addressId" => 146683,
            "customerId" => 144677,
        ),
        (object)array(
            "contactId" => 231567,
            "addressId" => 23453,
            "customerId" => 3453453,
        ),
        (object)array(
            "contactId" => 133004,
            "addressId" => 119729,
            "customerId" => 118853,
        ),
        (object)array(
            "contactId" => 174081,
            "addressId" => 153779,
            "customerId" => 151573,
        )
    );
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please update your question with some  example data, it would be easier to debug ...

Comment: sure, here you go. And it doesn't matter if the first array has integer as members of the objects.